# Using PostedFile.InputStream twice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stream, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm trying to resize one image to 5 different sizes (and then upload them to amazonS3).

I'm using imageresizer.net

the problem seems to be that i cannot use the inputstream twice. it works the first time.

```
    Dim SmallStream As Stream = New MemoryStream
    Dim TinyStream As Stream = New MemoryStream

    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        **ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, SmallStream, New ResizeSettings("maxwidth=100&maxheight=100"))
        ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, TinyStream, New ResizeSettings("maxwidth=100&maxheight=100"))**
        AmazonUploadFile("SmallImages/" & FileUpload1.FileName, SmallStream)
        AmazonUploadFile("TinyImages/" & FileUpload1.FileName, TinyStream)
    End If




Public Shared Function GetS3Client() As AmazonS3
    Dim appConfig As NameValueCollection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
    Dim s3Client As AmazonS3 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)
    Return s3Client
End Function

Public Sub AmazonUploadFile(S3Key As String, FileStream As Stream)
    Dim request As New PutObjectRequest()
    request.WithBucketName(BUCKET_NAME)
    request.WithKey(S3Key).InputStream = FileStream
    request.WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
    GetS3Client.PutObject(request)
End Sub
```

The code breaks when i try to retrieve the `FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream` the second time.

Comment: Reading the stream into an Image yourself will prevent the ImageResizer from avoiding the 8 associated pitfalls with that - and you'll also lose everything except frame 1 in multi-page TIFFs or animated GIFs. Please mark my answer as correct, so others will avoid the issues with NYSystemsAnalyst's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ImageResizer will accept Image objects to that method.  So, you could read the InputStream into an Image object first (Image.FromStream()), then you can use that image object repeatedly.

Comment: That's a beter approach than what I was thinking.  +1 to you.

Comment: It's actually better to not share an Image instance, although it's fine if you (a) wrap it in a using(){} clause, (b) don't need metadata or automatic exif rotation, (c) manually specify the image format you want it to be with `format` to prevent certain ambiguities, (d) aren't processing high volumes of PSD or RAW/CR2 images, and (e) don't want to support the FreeImage, WIC, or WPF pipelines.

If you pass a Bitmap instance in, don't use `sRotate` or `sFlip` unless you're not doing further work with the Bitmap instance.

Comment: The less you touch System.Drawing, the more optimizations the ImageResizer can  make to optimize image decoding, resizing, and memory management.

Answer (score 1):

**[Disclaimer: I'm the author of http://imageresizing.net/]**

Pass `FileUpload1.PostedFile` instead of `FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream` to the ImageResizer and it will automatically handle re-seeking the stream to the beginning after each read. (Make sure you're using 3.1.5 or later).

Alternatively, use the `ImageJob` class and set `ResetSourceStream=true`.